# Array to string conversion error in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am creating an event based website. I am using laravel for this with backbone. I am retrieving data from database using backbonejs with laravel as following

```
var events = new Events();
new EventsView({el: $("#calendar"), collection: events}).render();
events.fetch();
```

On the server side I have following controller

```
class Calendars_Controller extends Base_Controller {

public $restful = true;

public function get_index()
{
    //print_r(Calendar::all() );
    return Calendar::all();
}

}
```

But this returns following error

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

Array to string conversion
Location:

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/calendar/laravel/response.php on line 272
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using Laravel 4, you might want to try returning the following from your controller instead:

```
$events = Calendar::all();
return Response::eloquent($events);
```